# Плавное появление меню

Tags: javascript, css, прокрутка, menu

Есть фиксированное меню. Но оно появляется очень резко. Нужно добавить плавность.
CSS - файл

```
.sub-menu{
z-index: 1023;
height: 60px;
display: none;
background: #fff;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
transition: .4s ease;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 20px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.46);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 20px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.46);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 20px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.46);
}
```

JS-файл

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
if ($(document).width()>785) {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > ($('header').height() )) {        
        $('.sub-menu').show();
    } else {
        $('.sub-menu').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Нужно плавное появление сверху и такое же при исчезновении. HTML разметку добавлять не вижу смысла, так же как и другие элементы фиксированного меню, так как все обернуто в .sub-menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).width() > 785) {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > ($('header').height())) {
      $('.sub-menu').addClass('open');
    } else {
      $('.sub-menu').removeClass('open');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  z-index: 1023;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 20px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 20px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 20px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
}

.sub-menu.open {
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus accusamus saepe dignissimos et eveniet quae maxime expedita dolorem molestias, dolore est vitae sint non reiciendis, sequi perferendis facere corrupti veniam.</header>
<div class="sub-menu">

</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Architecto enim alias quia maxime, nulla pariatur ad eos tempore. Corrupti, temporibus. Assumenda nesciunt unde autem optio itaque sunt magni recusandae temporibus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, quas doloremque rerum minus dolores beatae dolore atque sunt fuga facere impedit cumque, quos eos excepturi adipisci earum voluptates, cupiditate enim.</p>
<p>Quos earum quisquam at assumenda quod repudiandae rerum, debitis maxime! Odit cupiditate nisi maxime cumque incidunt vel ipsum optio autem, facilis corrupti quod similique error eius nemo, at, est explicabo!</p>
<p>Facere consequuntur, quo earum, perspiciatis quisquam cum qui ad nam dolorum voluptatibus sunt labore delectus quasi voluptates. Distinctio harum sint perferendis, porro sit ratione. Eos magnam distinctio nihil voluptatibus labore?</p>
<p>Minima, illum assumenda iusto earum doloremque quasi qui quisquam, repudiandae provident sapiente possimus autem at nihil corrupti ullam? Inventore excepturi facilis consectetur voluptatem adipisci in enim dolorum dolores corporis! Fuga.</p>
<p>Corrupti incidunt perspiciatis rem veniam possimus libero dolores dolore harum? Reiciendis voluptatem quae architecto autem. Eveniet labore molestias inventore libero aperiam eius reprehenderit pariatur corporis accusantium nam, quidem sapiente quo.</p>
<p>Alias accusantium delectus laborum nulla facere architecto id explicabo quis reiciendis? Esse mollitia adipisci quasi optio nulla odit distinctio ab dolor itaque soluta quae debitis, labore ducimus reiciendis aspernatur eaque.</p>
<p>Molestias maiores ducimus, odio magni corrupti assumenda placeat. Repellat voluptatibus excepturi iure beatae ut deserunt expedita enim minus placeat labore, a nemo illo. Hic ea, cum facilis placeat sint omnis!</p>
<p>Repudiandae aperiam, explicabo ex vitae sequi rerum dolorum repellendus ullam at dicta temporibus in ipsam quae sit consequuntur minima dolorem. Dolorum officiis adipisci expedita obcaecati voluptate quod inventore fugiat non!</p>
<p>Fugit vel omnis, officia nam commodi, quisquam nobis velit vero ullam illum veritatis delectus expedita cum ipsam placeat sunt pariatur aliquid voluptatem possimus repellendus nihil? Eaque voluptatem architecto expedita hic!</p>
<p>Maiores libero quod quaerat nulla aperiam, voluptate cum. Totam exercitationem, laborum soluta optio rerum in quia cupiditate nesciunt illum nulla nam. Cum vel maxime ut tempore, repellat quasi quod provident.</p>
<p>Ratione consequuntur corporis necessitatibus dolorem illum sint dolore expedita, facilis, numquam voluptatibus ab nisi doloremque accusantium rem! Cupiditate unde delectus maiores, natus magnam eligendi repellendus laudantium tempora omnis, vel obcaecati.</p>
<p>Placeat eligendi nemo magnam. Consectetur error eveniet cupiditate quibusdam saepe. Rem assumenda ullam voluptatum similique provident. Quas ducimus error, et sunt rerum incidunt, neque voluptatibus velit porro dolores non totam.</p>
<p>Officiis recusandae quod vel saepe possimus corporis dolorem labore quis aperiam ex. Natus quae ex, ullam neque magni reprehenderit suscipit aut nostrum maxime voluptate est magnam, distinctio voluptas accusamus necessitatibus!</p>
<p>Voluptates officiis explicabo enim ut dolorem aliquid suscipit ratione eveniet amet molestias sed inventore veniam cumque, ipsa consequuntur sit, maiores alias assumenda dolorum! Iste odit officia ex cum tempora facere.</p>
<p>Unde sint eos illum neque libero, perferendis culpa et illo reprehenderit odio in minus earum reiciendis magnam soluta nostrum repellendus doloribus, impedit error ipsum? Praesentium unde sunt cum hic aspernatur.</p>
<p>Quas ducimus blanditiis est quaerat facilis unde illum esse itaque tempora soluta eaque, eum aliquid praesentium eveniet voluptatem corporis rem veritatis! Voluptatem debitis quod velit mollitia minus perspiciatis cupiditate est?</p>
<p>Ducimus itaque magnam odio esse placeat ratione, voluptas nam reprehenderit architecto labore in sed ipsam dicta sequi repellendus illum consectetur ut a voluptatum doloribus quidem! Repudiandae dolor facilis assumenda mollitia.</p>
<p>Recusandae maxime quisquam iure aliquid atque necessitatibus aspernatur dicta neque adipisci ducimus perferendis sint aliquam tempore numquam explicabo sequi et, voluptates quis laboriosam. Rerum, sequi quisquam doloribus facilis error repudiandae.</p>
<p>Vitae sed commodi sit hic fugiat aliquam, fugit vero deserunt quidem est! Temporibus fugit minima omnis necessitatibus quidem fuga quas quos consequatur, earum quasi repellendus quod optio totam voluptas repellat.</p>
<p>Repellendus maiores, quis nemo fuga nam eaque sequi. Consectetur culpa ex at, maiores enim eum hic quo, iste commodi illo error! Dolore quam ratione dicta accusamus, neque tenetur aliquam? Reprehenderit.</p>
<p>A ut unde optio rerum accusamus, aut perspiciatis, eos nisi, autem explicabo nulla accusantium porro architecto debitis? Cupiditate molestiae excepturi enim veniam alias dignissimos dolores, saepe commodi nobis pariatur non.</p>
<p>Molestiae ullam, possimus velit cum eveniet ratione asperiores rem cupiditate vero nostrum corrupti ea, voluptates officia provident sit esse quos. Illum natus, eius aspernatur amet similique consequuntur! Animi, magnam laudantium!</p>
<p>Soluta accusantium velit, ipsa nulla, officiis ipsam optio expedita nostrum, dignissimos et fugit cum. Dolorem voluptatibus error laudantium sunt suscipit dolores modi, soluta et! Officiis, laudantium. Laboriosam dolores maxime nobis!</p>
<p>Omnis quasi cum repellendus facilis animi, adipisci sequi et. Sit, veritatis. Labore, delectus eius itaque fuga inventore dolores harum, minus doloremque quos doloribus laboriosam facere sint reiciendis deleniti error! Labore?</p>
<p>Provident corporis minus dolorem, earum neque numquam odit velit tempora ea harum nostrum adipisci non deleniti ut dolorum officiis alias sint unde tenetur nobis iste vitae similique illo inventore. Id.</p>
```

Comment: Простите, не работает

Comment: работает, на весь экран сделайте.

Answer (score 0):

Если любитель js использовать, то .fadeIn('slow') и fadeOut('slow'), либо toggle()

а так можно через поиграть с css, блоку opacity 0 и transition.